# java rsa encryption SSLSocket, android to java problems

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, sslsocketfactory

I need to connect with a server over SSLSocket (not http/https) from android phone. I first generated jks keystore with private/public pair, and then a jks with only the public key for the client.
I then first tried setting up SSLSocketFactory from java to java, and I got it to work.
Android didn't accept my jks keystore so I converted it to bks for the android side.
However, when I test it, the server side throws a

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

The android side throws a

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Here is the code for the test-server:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","edkey.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
ServerSocketFactory ssocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket ssocket = ssocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);
System.out.println(ansiPurple("Starting"));
socket = ssocket.accept();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
....
```

Here is the code for the working java client:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","edkey_public.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
socket = (SSLSocket)f.createSocket(host, port);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
....
```

Here is the code for the non-working android app:

```
InputStream ki = a.getResources().openRawResource(a.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/edkey_public", "raw", a.getPackageName()));
KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
ks.load(ki,"password".toCharArray());
kmfactory.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());
ki.close();
KeyManager[] keymanagers =  kmfactory.getKeyManagers();
TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(keymanagers, tms, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory f=sslContext.getSocketFactory();
Socket socket = (SSLSocket)f.createSocket(host, port);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
....
```

Anyone know where the problem resides?

Comment: You didn't create the truststore correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it's because in the android app you say

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
```

which should be

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```